# Where can I find all the Stockholm Slussen construction banner texts?

Tags: stockholm

While visiting Stockholm I have noticed the Slussen construction which is affecting both locals and tourists. Stockholms Stad put some funny banners in an effort to alleviate the discomfort. The following are clearly targeting the tourists (written in English):

[image: Slussen 1]

[image: Slussen 2]

[image: Slussen 3]

[image: Slussen 4]

Unfortunately I have forgotten to take pictures of the texts targeting the locals (written in Svenska) and I would to find them. I have tried finding all of them, but I not able to find them all.

**Question:** Where can I find all the Stockholm Slussen construction banner texts?

Comment: How is this a travel question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to travel as defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send an email to the registrators of:

- The Stockholm Municipality
- The Stockholm Region (SLL)
- The Swedish Transport Agency
- or any other government agency involved.

The signs should be found in the public archives of some of these.

---

*In 2014 I was elected as a politician in Sweden with about 20 public roles.*